# How is instagram widgets pull user feeds without authenticating the user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram, instagram-api

I am aware of the new instagram API change which says that every request should now require the access token to fetch a user feeds, and to create an access token the user have to authenticate the application.

I wonder how some widget and jQuery plugins such as

- https://elfsight.com/instagram-feed-instashow/jquery
- http://dev.chrisriversdesign.com/jquery-instagram-browser/demo/index.html

is able to fetch the feeds of any user even when the user has not authenticated !!

I also see that there are other such as

- http://www.uptsi.com/tools/widgets/manage/
- https://snapwidget.com/
- https://lightwidget.com/

etc which requires the user to be authenticated to fetch the feed.

I have a requirement to use a plugin which can fetch feeds from 20 different users.

- Can these plugins work without me creating an access token ?
- Do I have to create 20 different tokens for them otherwise ?
- How are some of the plugins (listed above) are working without me providing token?

Thank you

Comment: some are using their own token to access, some are using random token generated by other apps (stolen)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Endpoints:

https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper/blob/master/src/InstagramScraper/Endpoints.php

They allow you to scrape public info